# How to index when partitioning for start and stop time columns in PostgreSql 12

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, partitioning, index-tuning, database-size

I have a log table that takes inserts at a rate of 5k-10k rows per second and number of records grow upwards of 20 Million every 24 hrs. Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.activity_log
(
    "Id" bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 
     START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    "StartTime" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone,    
    "EndTime" timestamp without time zone,    
    "InternalIp" inet,
    "MappedInternalIp" inet,
    "DestinationIp" inet,
    "DestinationPort" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,    
    "InternalPort" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "MappedInternalPort" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Protocol" character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "UserName" character varying(15) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "PK_activity_log" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)
    --------------------
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "IX_activity_log_ConnectionKey"
    ON public.activity_log USING btree
    ("ConnectionKey" COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX "IX_activity_log_EndTime"
    ON public.activity_log USING btree
    ("EndTime" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX "IX_activity_log_InternalIp"
    ON public.activity_log USING btree
    ("InternalIp" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX "IX_activity_log_StartTime"
    ON public.activity_log USING btree
    ("StartTime" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

This is a time series but time is not unique as many users may have overlapping connection times. I will have to consider both `StartTime` and `EndTime` when partitioning, but many queries may want to filter on one or more of the IP cols or `UserName`. I need help on what type of indexes to use if I partition on both `StartTime` and `EndTime` cols.

Comment: Welcome to dba.SE!  I'm sorry, but it's not clear what your question is. Please edit your question and explain what you are asking about. Thanks!

Comment: @dwhitemv I have mentioned the challenges I am facing and that I need some help with it. I think it boils down to how to partition and how to index, while keeping the high rate of inserts/updates in mind.

Answer (score 1):

dba.SE is a question-and-answer format site. It works best if you ask a discrete question. Since you have multiple, complicated issues and need significant performance, you are better served hiring a consultant to advise you.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it's just a comment. Provided this is a question-and-answer site you should not use answers in this way.

Comment: Definitely not an answer, however I shortened my question to give others some idea of what the problem is that I am facing. May be my expression is not as per your expectations but you can choose to pass or give your expert opinion.... chill!

Comment: @McNets comment is pointed at me and is valid. I wasn't happy with my answer and should have deleted it, but since OP has commented I'll leave it as is. I will do better in the future.